# out.write doesn't want the datatype double value(Java Servlet)

Tags: java, servlets

out.write doesn't 'double' value. Is there another way to do this? 
I marked the line with the problem. 
I look forward to receiving your continued support.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/ServletDemo")
public class ServletDemo extends HttpServlet {

    private double getFahrenheit(double celsius){
        double fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32;
        return fahrenheit;
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");       
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("!DOCTYPE html>\n");
        out.write("<html>\n");
        out.write("<body>\n");
        out.write("<h1>JSP Beispiel</h1>\n");
        out.write("Text aus dem Scriplet!");
        out.write("<br/>\n");
        out.write("30&deg; Celsius entsprechen\n");
        out.write(getFahrenheit(30.0)); // ----------> Problem at this line
        out.write("&deg; Fahrenheit!\n");
        out.write("</body>\n");
        out.write("</html>");
        out.close();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PrintWriter.write()` with a single parameter can take either a `String`, `char[]` or an `int`; but not a `double`. Convert your value to a `String` by doing:

```
out.write(String.valueOf(getFahrenheit(30.0)));
```

or just

```
out.write(getFahrenheit(30.0) + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

`PrintWriter#write` prints either one character or string literal. You may convert double to string and write it or Use `PrintWriter#print` method to print double.

Use `String.valueOf()` convert double value to string literal.

Snippet:

```
out.write(String.valueOf(getFahrenheit(30.0)));
```

or

```
out.print(getFahrenheit(30.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

With a PrintWriter you can not "write" double but according to
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html
you can print them

`out.print(getFahrenheit(30.0));` would that be, also it is possible to
`out.write(""+getFahrenheit(30.0));` do something like that, if at some point you have something that does only support string types